# Odoo Add custom UI element to customer portal

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

This is the customer portal of odoo

[image: customer portal]

Im building my own module that generates plans for my business for every customer as an image and saves that image to a data model that has a One to One Relation to the customer

I would like to display this exact image on the customer portal, maybe in a new tab like "plan" just like the tabs on the screenshot (for example, you can click on Invoices ("Angebote") and you get an overview of all invoices. I want to do the same with my module).
I dont know how to do to it and I have already searched online but unfortunately not yet found any hint on how to do it.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Answering would be a bit much here, but i can give some starting points. The portal "my account" website is served by a [controller](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/developer/reference/addons/http.html). The website itself is a extendable QWeb view, so it shouldn't be that much a challenge to get your own new "tab" there. The "tabs" have URLs using controllers again. Just try to look into Tasks (Aufgaben), how it's done in Odoo. That should help a lot.

Comment: Here for example the [my tasks controller](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/project/controllers/portal.py#L103-L223), the [my tasks QWeb template](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/project/views/project_portal_templates.xml#L120-L171) and the [my tasks "tab" extension](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/project/views/project_portal_templates.xml#L29-L33)

Comment: @CZoellner I now have successfully created the controller and also added the "tab" to the customer portal. Can you tell me, how to query user specific information on that webpage? Because every logged in customer needs to see their own specific dataset from my module. Basically I would need to know, which user has logged in.. is this possible?

Comment: You usually have to use some special access rules (ir.rule) for that. There are also examples for that in the project modules.